# Aurelia .NET Core - Local files not found

Tags: aurelia

I'm hosting an Aurelia application in .NET Core set up by Aurelia CLI.

I have included the Font-Awesome CSS file using `require` in my app.html file. 
Everything loads as it should but when I try to reference the Font-Awesome **fonts** located in `src/assets/icons/font-awesome` folder, (I have copied them there myself), I get the standard file not found console  error.

If I move my Font-Awesome fonts to the `wwwwroot` everything works and the icons appear on my page. My guess is that because I'm hosting my application through .NET Core, (wwwroot), I cant access static files under the src folder?

**Structure:**

[image]

**Console error:**

[image]

Why is it like this? Can I somehow go around this problem or am I forced to store my Font-Awesome fonts in wwwroot?

Next time when I start a new Aurelia project using Aurelia CLI, would it be better if I installed the Aurelia application inside the wwwroot, instead of a separate src folder in root?

Comment: wwwroot is meant as the "public" folder for assets.  Just move them there there is no reason to put something in `src` that is not a file that needs compiling or building in some way.  Better yet load them from a CDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default .NET Core web host serves static files from `wwwroot` folder.
There is a special instruction for that in your `Program.cs` file

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) //serve static from web root (wwwroot) folder
}
```

and somewhere in `Startup.cs` you have enabled static files middleware:
`app.UseStaticFiles(); //uses web root (wwwroot folder) by default`

To serve files from different location you want to call again this middleware with different configuration

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "src")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/src")
    });
```

But I will not recommend that. Good practice is store your code, assets, configuration separately, and bundle them to `wwwroot` directory as static files (using task managers, webpack or just copy for production)

[More info about static files management in .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files)

Comment: I've tried your custom configuration but all I got on port:5000 is an empty page. What could be the reason? What if I develop on port:9000, (provided by aurelia), instead of port:5000, (provided by .NET)? Then this solution wouldn't help? Without your custom configuration, shouldn't the root directory by default be src if I use port:9000? Then I should be able to load Fonts without setting another root?

Comment: I got it working now on port:5000, however static files are still not found on port:9000. Do you know a fix? I don't have browsersync on port:5000 so I would like to develop my app on port:9000. Thanks

Comment: If I follow your suggestion and don't change the root folder, am I supposed to have one asset folder in src containing my less files etc and one asset folder in wwwroot containing my font awesome fonts etc..? (I cant reference stylesheets in wwwroot)

Comment: @Reft did you setup Kestrel server on 9000 port?